# Guid problem while attempting to write data in database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, in-memory-database

I'm trying to write a Food Delivery app which has entities `Food` and `Order`.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Food> Foods { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
}

public class Food
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FoodId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

The problem occurs when a new `Order` is being created, because I'm passing the Guid `Id` from `Food` in `ICollection<Food> Foods`. I'm using MediatR for handling user actions, and mapping between `CreateOrderCommand` class and `Order` class itself.

The exception that is caught is claiming that the problem is that Guid from `ICollection<Food>` already exists. How should I map the collection of foods otherwise, or should I change Guid to simple int or string for my Ids?

> "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 36708fa9-71df-4141-95d6-a73a65cd5dce"

This is the exception caught in postman while trying to add new order in OrderRepository, with the Key being the Guid from Food which is passed as parameter.

```
    public class CreateOrderCommand : IRequest<Guid>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Food> Foods { get; set; }
}
```

This is the data that is being received from the front end app

```
public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var order = _mapper.Map<Order>(request);
        order.OrderTime = DateTime.Now;
        var user = await _userRepository.GetByUserNameAsync(request.UserName);
        GeoCoordinate userLocation = new GeoCoordinate(user.Latitude, user.Longitude);

        List<Restaurant> restaurants = (List<Restaurant>)await _restaurantRepository.ListAllAsync();
        List<double> distances = new List<double>();

        double minValue = 0;
        int minValuePosition = -1;

        //pronadji udaljenosti
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.Count; i++)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - restaurants[i].LastOrdered;
            if(ts.TotalMinutes >= 15)
            {
                GeoCoordinate restaurantCoords = new GeoCoordinate(restaurants[i].Latitude, restaurants[i].Longitude);
                distances.Add(userLocation.GetDistanceTo(restaurantCoords));
                minValue = distances[i];
                minValuePosition = i;
            }
            else
            {
                distances[i] = -1;
            }
        }

        //pronadji najmanju udaljenost koja je na listi
        for (int i = 0; i < distances.Count; i++)
        {
            if (distances[i] < 0)
                continue;
            if (distances[i] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = distances[i];
                minValuePosition = i;
            }
        }

        
        if(minValuePosition == -1)
        {
            //nema slobodnih restorana
            throw new Exception();
        }

        order.UserName = user.UserName;
        order.Foods = request.Foods;

        foreach(Food f in request.Foods)
        {
            order.OrderTotal += f.Price;
        }

        order = await _orderRepository.AddAsync(order);

        return order.OrderId;
    }
```

This is the handler for the data.

Comment: _"The exception that is caught is claiming that the problem is that Guid from ICollection already exists"_ - please post verbatim exception messages, not your interpreation. Is the actual error something like _"An error occurred while saving changes. Error details: The instance of entity type 'Food' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked"_? Then make sure your code doesn't run two instances of the same entities across the DbContext.

Comment: I added the error code, but as i stated the error is with the Guid.  Just dont know why

Comment: Provide a [mre] then. There's probably something in your mapping code that adds the same food twice, or whatever.

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] using the classes you have provided.

Comment: Hope this edit helps

Comment: @CodeCaster while debuging i noticed that the exception is being thrown in the OrderDbContext, and the FoodDbContext is not being called anywhere, so the duplication of the Food is not the issue here, or am i wrong? The problem i believe is with the uniqueness of the Guid , but im curious how the two different tables affect the Guid uniqueness

Comment: Why do you have two different context? Might be part of the problem.

Comment: And also, the code that calls `Handle()` might do a query to look up food, `_mapper.Map()` may map this again, causing some entities to be duplicated somewhere.

Comment: My bad about the context, i have one i meant FoodRepo and OrderRepo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that your Food entity represents a catalog of what food is available, each with its own Guid unique identifier.

Now, I think, you're trying to create an order in the Order context that 'uses' foods items identified in your Food context.

In this situation, if the same food item appears twice in the same order, or appears in other orders, then because you are using the unique identifier of the food resource as the unique key for an item in your Order aggregate you will get PK constraints errors like the one above.

I think you need two separate entities:

- Food
- OrderItem (which refers to a food)

The OrderItem should have its own unique key, with a column that includes the id of the food.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public Guid FoodId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Food
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FoodId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The column which includes the id of the food would still be a problem if i fill it with the original Food Guid no?

Comment: Your problem at the moment is because its a Primary Key (which must be unique).  If the PK was another value created as a unique identifier for the order item then this problem is resolved.  You'd then move the Food Id to another column that is not the primary key and therefore not implicitly unique.  You can add an index for it if you wish, but make sure that the index does not have a unique constraint.

Comment: Have added a proposed entity model.  Note that Order now has a collection of OrderItems, each of which points to a food.

Comment: Guid by itself is unique right? The problem wasnt the uniqueness of the key, but the uniqueness of the Guid value

Comment: Yes, Guid.NewGuid() will generate a unique key.  If you're getting PK violations that you're trying to insert another copy of Food with the same Id.  My answer made the assumption that the Food record already exists in your database before you're trying to add it to an Order.  When you add it to the order in the Order context, EF will try to insert a new record.

Comment: Thank you so much I tried it now and it works.

Comment: You're welcome.  Give the answer a tick if it solved your problem.  Cheers!